# config.h file not found and :CFBundleIdentifier does not exist. ERROR

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have tried everything I found on the internet to solve this problem but still gives me the same error

I have tried this few times:

```
$ rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install
$ ls node_modules/react-native/ (missing third-party directory)
```

Xcode build fails: 'config.h' file not found

```
$ node_modules/react-native/ios-install-third-party.sh or node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh
$ ls node_modules/react-native/ (third-party directory found)

    react-native run-ios
Found Xcode project albums.xcodeproj
Building using "xcodebuild -project albums.xcodeproj -configuration Debug -scheme albums -destination id=1ADEA58D-63BF-431C-B743-C1B73366A9B8 -derivedDataPath build"
    Capabilities for albums may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the build settings editor. (in target 'albums')
▸ Running script 'Install Third Party'
▸ Compiling raw_logging.cc

❌  /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React Native + Redux - Steven Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: 'config.h' file not found

#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling signalhandler.cc

❌  /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React Native + Redux - Steven Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: 'config.h' file not found

#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling Conv.cpp
▸ Compiling StringBase.cpp
▸ Compiling dynamic.cpp
▸ Compiling utilities.cc

❌  /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React Native + Redux - Steven Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: 'config.h' file not found

#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling vlog_is_on.cc

❌  /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React Native + Redux - Steven Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: 'config.h' file not found

#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling Unicode.cpp
▸ Compiling symbolize.cc

❌  /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React Native + Redux - Steven Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/base/mutex.h:105:10: 'config.h' file not found

#include "config.h"           // to figure out pthreads support
         ^~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling Bits.cpp
▸ Compiling demangle.cc

❌  /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React Native + Redux - Steven Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/demangle.h:73:10: 'config.h' file not found

#include "config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~


▸ Compiling Demangle.cpp
** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:

    CompileC /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React\ Native\ +\ Redux\ -\ Steven\ Grider/albums/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/React.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/third-party.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/demangle-9e475ebb43be38e662a2b7ccf64e02d2c67a869564183b68ceff63bc9453d1d1.o /Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React\ Native\ +\ Redux\ -\ Steven\ Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/third-party/glog-0.3.5/src/demangle.cc normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/albums.app
An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/albums.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist


Error: Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/albums.app/Info.plist
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:602:13)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:622:13)
    at Promise.then (/Users/servandoberna/Downloads/React Native + Redux - Steven Grider/albums/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/runIOS/runIOS.js:208:5)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:189:7)
```

Environment:

> OSX - Mojave
>   Node - 8.12.0
>   react-native-cli - 2.0.1
>   react-native - 0.33.0
>   Xcode - 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Work with xCode 10

```
$ cd ./node_modules/react-native && scripts/ios-install-third-party.sh && cd third-party && cd $(ls | grep 'glog' | awk '{print $1}') && ./configure
```

Comment: I have the same problem as Servando, and this does the trick for development but not for production. I can build and run the jsbundle on a physical device, but the same error persists when I try the Archive command. Do you know how to fix it? Thanks!